# Searching in specific indices with JSON object

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, elasticsearch-dsl

I have a problem. In my application I'm using ElasticSearch. I'm posting JSON object to my ElasticSearch server. That JSON object contain DSL query. So, what I need to do, is to query specific index for some data.

This is the query:

```
{  
   "query":{  
      "indices":{  
         "indices":[  
            "index-1"
         ],
         "query":{  
            "bool":{  
               "must":[  
                  {  
                     "match":{  
                        "_all":"this is test"
                     }
                  }
               ],
               "should":[  
                  {  
                     "match":{  
                        "country":"PL"
                     }
                  }
               ],
               "minimum_should_match":1
            }
         },
         "no_match_query":"none"
      }
   },
   "from":0,
   "size":10,
   "sort":{  
      "name":{  
         "order":"ASC"
      }
   }
}
```

Query works just fine, it returns data which I want to. However, in ElasticSearch logs I can see:

```
[2015-05-28 22:08:20,942][DEBUG][action.search.type] [index] [twitter][0], node[X_ASxSKmn-Bzmn-nHLQ8g], [P], s[STARTED]: Failed to execute [org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequest@7b98e9ad] lastShard [true]
org.elasticsearch.search.SearchParseException: [twitter][0]: query[MatchNoDocsQuery],from[0],size[10]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [HERE_COMES_MY_JSON]]
        at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:681)
        at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createContext(SearchService.java:537)
        at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createAndPutContext(SearchService.java:509)
        at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:264)
        at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$5.call(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:231)
        at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$5.call(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:228)
        at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$23.run(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:559)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.search.SearchParseException: [twitter][0]: query[MatchNoDocsQuery],from[0],size[10]: Parse Failure [No mapping found for [name] in order to sort on]
```

It tries to fetch something from twitter index, which is some standard out-of-the-box index for testing. Why? I specified that I want to search in index-1, not all of them.

I found workaround, just to add:
`"ignore_unmapped" : true`
in sort, but it's not really a solution.

I don't know if it matters, but I set up a REST which I'm calling, and inside my Java app I'm passing JSON to ElasticSearch like that:

```
Client client = new TransportClient(settings);
SearchRequestBuilder builder = client .prepareSearch().setSource(json);
SearchResponse response = builder.execute().actionGet();
```

Anyone have any clue what is wrong? I would really appreciate any

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the functionality of `indices` here: it can be used when a certain query needs to be executed against a list of indices **and** another query that needs to be executed on indices that **do not match** the list of indices.

So, all depends on the indices you run this against.

For example:

```
GET /abc,test1,test2,test3/_search
{
  "query": {
    "indices": {
      "indices": ["abc"],
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
...
```

will be run against `abc, test1, test2, test3` indices. Indices that match `"indices": ["abc"]` will have the `query` run against. The other indices that don't match (in my example - `test1, test2, test3`) will have the query from `no_match_query` run against them.

So, it is important against which indices you run your `indices` query. And [ignoring unmapped fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_ignoring_unmapped_fields) is the way to go here.

Comment: Okay, that make sense. So if I want to run ONLY on specific index, I need to in Java specify it like that: client.prepareSearch().setIndices("index-1").setSource(json); I'm worried about performance when I will have many indices

Comment: Yes, using `setIndices(...)` should do it.